# how to prove Zorn from basis existence theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

today a student asked me how to prove Zorn's lemma from the assumption that "every vector space has a (Hamel) basis". Now, I know how to prove AC from the basis existence, and I also know how to prove ZL from AC, but I was curious if there was a more rapid proof of Zorn's lemma directly using the fact that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: It is still an open problem whether the axiom of foundation is required to prove the equivalence. Given this, I find it extremely unlikely that there’s a clean proof of ZL that you’re looking for.

Comment: Oh, that's sad, but thank you! Yeah Zorn is a hard beast to prove

Comment: The point is that you can't even prove AC *directly* from the existence of bases. You have to go through an intermediate form first.